# proportion of $n$ symbol sequences whose $l^p$ norm is equal to $|[n]|_p$

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics

and each symbol is at most $n$...

Any ideas about where to find previous work?

I can find the answers for small $n$ using a brute force search, but I'd like to know more generally.

For example,
$1^3+2^3+3^3+4^3+5^3+6^3+7^3 = 784$

Of the sequences of length $n$ using the symbols in $\{1,\ldots, n\}$, 5460 of them have this same sum of cubes.  $5460-7!$ of them are not permutations of $[n]$.  The same thing happens with the sum of fourth powers (but not when $p=5$).

1. For which $p$ is the norm of a permutation of $[n]$ distinct from the norm of these other sequences?
2. Otherwise, what is the proportion of "false positives"?
3. Is there a $p_0$ for which $p>p_0$ always gives this distinction?  What is $p_0$?

Comment: needless to say, I can cut some of the computation by considering multisets of size $n$ on $n$ symbols.